# Simple sans serif Psi with default fonts?

Tags: greek

The default fonts in LaTeX are fine for my purposes. However, for some math formulas, I'm finding the Greek capital Psi letter to be a bit "out of context" because of the heavy serifs in its central vertical bar. With such heavy serifs, it makes me feel like if I'm talking about Psychology instead of maths.

I tried `\varPsi` which looks better because it's italic, but still, the serifs are huge, and too Psychology-like for my taste.

I know there are packages for loading alternate fonts, but... is there any simpler way of getting a "cleaner" capital Psi without changing the default fonts? (at least with lighter serifs). I don't like the idea of loading packages and changing fonts just because of one letter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the `\Psi` from `cmbright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmbrightop}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sfPsi}{\mathalpha}{cmbrightop}{9}

\begin{document}

$\psi \Psi \sfPsi$

\end{document}
```

[image]